# Migrate old code of paging3 with lazyColumn

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-paging, android-paging-3, lazycolumn

In this demo app, I've implemented paging3 with jetpack compose, but in ListContent I got this error after updating the all dependencies to the latest version, I try to pass items and the key as `unsplashImage.id` it's look the lazyColumn in newer version has different params

[image]

this my ListContent file

```
@ExperimentalCoilApi
@Composable
fun ListContent(items: LazyPagingItems<UnsplashImage>) {
    Log.d("Error", items.loadState.toString())
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(all = 12.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp)
    ) {
        items(
            items = items,
            key = { unsplashImage ->
                unsplashImage.id
            }
        ) { unsplashImage ->
            unsplashImage?.let { UnsplashItem(unsplashImage = it) }
        }
    }
}

@ExperimentalCoilApi
@Composable
fun UnsplashItem(unsplashImage: UnsplashImage) {
    val painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
        model = unsplashImage.urls.regular,
        error = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_placeholder),
        placeholder = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_placeholder)
    )
    val context = LocalContext.current
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .clickable {
                val browserIntent = Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("https://unsplash.com/@${unsplashImage.user.username}?utm_source=DemoApp&utm_medium=referral")
                )
                ContextCompat.startActivity(context, browserIntent, null)
            }
            .height(300.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter
    ) {
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            painter = painter,
            contentDescription = "Unsplash Image",
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
        )
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(40.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .alpha(0.5F),
            color = Color.Black
        ) {}
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(40.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(horizontal = 6.dp),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
        ) {
            Text(
                text = buildAnnotatedString {
                    append("Photo by ")
                    withStyle(style = SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Black)) {
                        append(unsplashImage.user.username)
                    }
                    append(" on Unsplash")
                },
                color = Color.White,
                fontSize = MaterialTheme.typography.titleSmall.fontSize,
                maxLines = 1,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
            )
            LikeCounter(
                modifier = Modifier.weight(3f),
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_heart),
                likes = "${unsplashImage.likes}"
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun LikeCounter(
    modifier: Modifier,
    painter: Painter,
    likes: String
) {
    Row(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End
    ) {
        Icon(
            painter = painter,
            contentDescription = "Heart Icon",
            tint = HeartRed
        )
        Divider(modifier = Modifier.width(6.dp))
        Text(
            text = likes,
            color = Color.White,
            fontSize = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge.fontSize,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            maxLines = 1,
            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
        )
    }
}

@ExperimentalCoilApi
@Composable
@Preview
fun UnsplashImagePreview() {
    UnsplashItem(
        unsplashImage = UnsplashImage(
            id = "1",
            urls = Urls(regular = ""),
            likes = 100,
            user = User(username = "Midomidoman", userLinks = UserLinks(html = ""))
        )
    )
}
```

and the model

```
@Serializable
@Entity(tableName = UNSPLASH_IMAGE_TABLE)
data class UnsplashImage(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    val id: String,
    @Embedded
    val urls: Urls,
    val likes: Int,
    @Embedded
    val user: User
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the [Paging Compose 1.0.0-alpha19 release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/paging#1.0.0-alpha19), the Paging Compose API was changed to support any kind of lazy layout (instead of just `LazyColumn` and `LazyRow`). This means you use the normal `items` method that takes a item count and the new `itemKey` extension method on `LazyPagingItems`.

So you should follow the updated [Paging Compose guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#large-datasets) to write your `LazyColumn` as:

```
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(all = 12.dp),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp)
) {
    items(
        items.itemCount,
        key = lazyPagingItems.itemKey { unsplashImage ->
            unsplashImage.id
        }
    ) { index ->
        items[index]?.let { UnsplashItem(unsplashImage = it) }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, this worked but I got `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 30, Size: 30` when I reach the item number 30

Comment: If you log your `items.itemCount` and log the `index` you're given, you should always see `index` between `0` and `itemCount - 1`. Otherwise I'd file a bug against `LazyColumn`.

Comment: I logged it and got this `ListContent: 40` and the last index logged is 30, this [UnsplashPaging3Demo](https://github.com/MML-Pro/UnsplashPaging3Demo) my whole code in GitHub if you can check it I will be grateful

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(all = 12.dp),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp)
) {
    items(
        key = { index ->
            items[index].id
        },
        count = items.size
    ) { index ->
        UnsplashItem[index]
    }
}
```